# Elasticsearch - object type, search nested elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch version 7.2.0 and have the following type in my mapping:

```
"status_change": {
  "type": "object",
  "enabled": false
},
```

Example of the data inside this field:

```
"before": {
  "status_type": "Status One"
},
"after": {
  "status_type": "Status Two"
}
```

There are various status_types and I am attempting to create a query to identify changes from specified before status_type to specified after status type. I'm struggling to query by these nested elements and the following query fails:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": {
          "match_all": {}
       },
       "filter": {
         "nested": {
           "path": "status_change",
           "query": {
              "term": {
                 "status_change.before": "the_before_status"
              }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

With:

```
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
  "reason" : "[nested] nested object under path [status_change] is not of nested type"
}
```

Which is self explanatory, due to status_change not being a 'nested' field. I have tried looking at searching objects by their nested elements but I have not found a solution.

Is there a way for me to search the nested object elements like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making use of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type but an [`object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type. There is a difference and I'd suggest you to go through the aforementioned links.

### If you are using Nested Type

Change your mapping to the below:

```
"status_change": {
  "type": "nested"
}
```

Once you do that and then reindex the documents, the query you have, would simply return the list of documents containing `status_change.before: the_before_status` irrespective of what value you have under `status_change.after` in your documents.

For further filtering based on `status_change.after`, add another `must` clause with that field to return documents you are looking for.

### If you are using Object Type

Simply remove the field `enabled: false` from your mapping and change your query to the below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status_change.before.status_type": "the_before_status"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: There's no need to use nested type if the OP doesn't intend to index arrays of objects into the field. a simple object type, (without the enabled=false, and with mapping each property) would suffice. See example here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html

Comment: @DoronYaacoby sorry I was still updating my answer with the alternative option what you mentioned.

Comment: Cheers, this was what I was afraid of with a cluster of ~ 1 bn records, but thanks for the confirmation :)